# Get value from table in Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm working on a table using the ng2-smart-table library and I'm having a hard time passing the values ​​entered in the edit line to a custom component:

See the code below in order to pass the Maximum and Minimum Temperature values ​​to the SmartTableEditorFunctionsComponent component when inserting a new row in the table.

```
    temperaturaMaxima: {
    type: 'number',
    title: 'Temperatura Máxima',
  },
  temperaturaMinima: {
    title: 'Temperatura Mínima',
    type: 'number',
  },
  temperaturaMedia: {
    title: 'Temperatura Média',
    type: 'number',
    editor: {
      type: 'custom',
      component: SmartTableEditorFunctionsComponent,
      valuePrepareFunction(instance) {
        instance.save.subscribe();
      },
    },
  },
```

Table image:
[enter image description here][1]

I created a button to try to retrieve the value, but without success.
Component code:

```
  export class SmartTableEditorFunctionsComponent extends DefaultEditor {
  @Input() value: string | number;
  @Input() rowData: any;
  @Output() save: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  getPlaceholder(value: any) {
    const id = value.column.temperaturaMaxima;
    return id;
  }

  test() {
    const id = this.rowData.temperaturaMaxima;
    alert('TESTE' + id);
  }
}
```

Component template code:

```
   {{ cell.newValue }}
<input
  type="number"
  [(ngModel)]="cell.newValue"
  [name]="cell.getId()"
  [placeholder]="cell.getTitle()"
  [disabled]="!cell.isEditable()"
  (click)="onClick.emit($event)"
/>
```

<button (click)="test()">Pega Valor

can anybody help me?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QF1Y.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems you try to read from

```
    @Input() rowData: any;
```

but you never assign any value to it. I don't know if the smart-table is supposed to populate those variables for you but maybe you just forgot to pass data to your component.

Somewhere in your template you need to pass data into it like in the input you've shown

```
    [rowData]="your_data"
```

Comment: I did a test here and managed to get the data from the table to pass to the component.

Comment: `temperaturaMinima: {
        title: 'Temperatura Mínima',
        type: 'custom',
        renderComponent: SmartTableEditorFunctionsComponent,
        valuePrepareFunction: (value, row, cell) => {
          console.log('editor', value);
        },
        sort: false,
        editable: true,
        onComponentInitFunction: (instance: any) => {
          instance.save.subscribe(row => {
            // this.source.refresh();
            console.log('row', row);
          });
        },
      },`